# Go to particular line inside a procedure/function/package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

is there any faster way to go to the particular line in Oracle SQL Developer. I remember a certain line where my function is called, but i don't want to scroll down every time when i need to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to press ctrl-G (go to line ) and and enter appropriate line number and you will be navigated to the entered line.

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl-G.  SQL*Developer will open a dialog asking you what line number you want to go to.